# findIndex() returns as -1 and not correct index number

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage

Struggling with this one. It was working before and not sure, why it is not now...

I have a ToDo app, containing a form, with two inputs - one for **name**. And one for **url**.

I should be able to edit any input value. And then save/update the updated array object, in local storage.

If I click on my edit button, without changing an input value, the correct index number is returned, (0 or 1).

But if I change an input value. And THEN click the edit value, **-1** is returned. 
And therefore, the rest of my function does not work, as my JS is not finding the correct index to update, the  object with.

Here's a snippet of the code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
bookmarksArray: [
    {
        "name": "jane",
        "url": "http://www.jane.co.uk/"
    },
    {
        "name": "mark",
        "url": "http://www.google.com"
    }
]

  // UPDATE/EDIT EXISTING BOOKMARK
  list.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('js-edit-url')) {
      const editName = event.target.parentElement.name.value;
      const editURL = event.target.parentElement.url.value;
      let constUpdatedOBj = {name: editName, url: editURL};

      const objIndex = bookMarksArray.findIndex(obj => obj.name === editName);

      console.log('editName', editName);
      console.log('editURL', editURL);
      console.log('objIndex', objIndex);

      bookMarksArray[objIndex] = constUpdatedOBj;
      window.localStorage.setItem("bookMarksArray", JSON.stringify(bookMarksArray));
    }
  });
```

Comment: We should know the value of `bookmarksArray` (with your current example) at the beginning of the click event handler function to properly help you (what does a console log show?). Also if you try to edit the name value, it's normal you can't find the item, because you search it by name and it just changed (in that case, adding an `id` field would be mandatory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as I would expect it to, if you start out with your array like so:

```
bookmarksArray: [
    {
        "name": "jane",
        "url": "http://www.jane.co.uk/"
    },
    {
        "name": "mark",
        "url": "http://www.google.com"
    }
];
```

And then the name `mark` is edited in the input to `tony`, this is essentially what you're getting:

```
const objIndex = bookMarksArray.findIndex(obj => obj.name === 'tony');
```

"tony" doesn't exist in the `bookmarksArray` so findIndex is going to return a `-1`.

What you need is an id on those bookmarks:

```
bookmarksArray: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "jane",
        "url": "http://www.jane.co.uk/"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "mark",
        "url": "http://www.google.com"
    }
];
```

And then have your `findIndex` look for the correct record based on the id:

```
const bookmarkId = event.target.parentElement.id.value;
const objIndex = bookMarksArray.findIndex(obj => obj.id === bookmarkId);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @nerdy beast, this was really helpful!